# Meaning of も in Xは日本でも有名だ

Tags: particle-も, particle-でも

> 新潟県長岡市の花火大会は日本で**も**有名で、２日間で１００万人が見に来ます。
>   Nagaoka's firework display is famous in Japan, and 1 million people will come to see it over a two day period.

What does the も (in bold) add to this sentence? The meanings of 'also'/'even' don't seem appropriate here.

Comment: Your missing link: https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011561351000/k10011561351000.html

Comment: @user27280 I have thought about adding links for NHK articles, but since they expire in a month I decided it wasn't worth it unless it added useful context. Maybe a question for meta.

Comment: In that context I understand your decision, but as it is difficult to determine whether the surrounding  context will be useful without viewing it for oneself I believe a short-lived link is probably better than none. I'm not sure what the general consensus is though.

Comment: maybe just add a note saying "this NHK link will expire after (date)" for links with a know expiry date.

Comment: are you SURE that も doesn't mean "also/even"? It doesn't seem like too big a stretch, given that the article is geared toward a foreign readership...

Comment: I'll expand this for you: ...の花火大会は（長岡、新潟）だけではなく日本でも有名で

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think by 「日本」 the writer meant "all of Japan" as opposed to just 長岡市 or 新潟県. That is the only justification for using 「も」 I can come up with. But in that case 「全国」 or 「日本中」 would be a more appropriate word. As written it sounds to me as if the fireworks were first and foremost famous outside Japan or 新潟県長岡市 weren't located in the country.

So the 「も」 has its usual meaning of "also/even", but the「日本」 is used with a slightly unexpected meaning. I take that the general drift of the sentence is "Nagaoka's firework display is famous outside it's locale too, and so it draws a million people from across the country over a two-day period."

Comment: As I commented below the question, I think any "unusual" phrasings are probably out of consideration for the likely readership of the article. 「日本」is probably a more accessible word than 「全国」

Comment: That may be, but IMO the accessibility of words shouldn't be prioritized over the observance of widely agreed-upon meaning and usage. The meaning of difficult words can be found in dictionaries, but meaning/usage that words don't have can't.

Comment: There's also the the possibility that it's a typo... Nobody's perfect...

Comment: That may very well be the case -- a little lapse in attention.

Comment: heh. although now that I think about it, typos have to be a lot harder to do in Japanese, given the way that keystrokes translate into kana...